# TV's so loud when I turn over

Tags: brain, sleep, hearing, human-ear

Scenario: I'm about to fall asleep with the T.V. on. Having completely forgotten that it was, no longer even *hearing* it, just before falling asleep I turn over with a 'fresh' ear and it's blaring. If I roll back over it will be noticeable, but quiet again. Waking hours my ears are fine, no worries. Is this some weird sleep induced brain shut-down going on?

Comment: I've noticed a similar thing. I think your ear adapts to the sound level it is being hit with, so when you turn over, the ear that was used to hearing absolutely nothing comes up, adapted to find the weakest signals. You can do something similar with your eyes. Cover one for a few minutes, then open it and close the other. The room will seem quite bright. Or, look through a cardboard paper towel tube with one eye for a while. The view through the tube will get much brighter, as that eye is being hit with considerably less light.